# populate select options from extra mysql table data

Tags: php, mysql, wpdb

hi guys i am trying to populate a select element with options from the data in one of my sql tables heres what i have so far:

```
 <?
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM pt_country ORDER BY name";
    $rs = $wpdb->query($SQL);
    $nr = mysql_num_rows($rs);
        for ($i=0; $i<$nr; $i++) {
        $r = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
        echo "<OPTION VALUE=\"".$r["countrycode"]."\">".$r["country"]."</OPTION>";
       }
?>
```

im guessing quite a bit of this is wrong but to start with i cant get wordpress to return the data i just get false what am i missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use mysql_fetch_array()

Use wordpress built-in functions, like this:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM pt_country ORDER BY name";
$rows = $wpdb->get_results( $SQL );
foreach($rows as $r){
 print_r($r);
}
```